# Split selectCheckBox into two columns?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, selectlist

I would like to use a selectCheckbox for a field but the design team wants the options to be in two columns like so

```
opt 1 | opt 2
-------------
opt 3 | opt 4
-------------
opt 5 |
```

Im sure I could work around this using single checkboxes and putting them in a panel grid but Id rather just use selectcheckboxes. Is there a simple way to do this with out using jQuery (javascript is ok just not preferred).

Answer (score -1):

II had done this earlier.Hope this help.There's probably a few ways to do this, the way I'd approach it is to put the items into a wrapper class that contains up to three instances of your object.

eg Controller

```
public MyController
{
 public List<MyWrapper> myWrappers{get; set;}
 public class MyWrapper
 {
  public Account myAcc1 {get; set;}
  public Account myAcc2 {get; set;}
  public Account myAcc3 {get; set;}

  public Boolean checkbox1 {get; set;}
  public Boolean checkbox2 {get; set;}
  public Boolean checkbox3 {get; set;}
 }
   public MyController()
    {
    myWrappers=new List<MyWrapper>();
    Integer idx=0;
    MyWrapper wrap;

    for (Account acc: [select id, Name from Account limit 12])
  {
     if (0==Math.mod(idx, 3))
     {
        wrap=new MyWrapper();
        wrap.myAcc1=acc;
     }
     if (1==Math.mod(idx, 3)
     {
        wrap.myAcc2=acc;
     }
     else if (2==Math.mod(idx, 3)
     {
        wrap.myAcc3=acc;
       }
      }
    }
 }
Page:
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!MyWrappers}" var="wrap">
   <apex:column headerValue="Col 1">
    <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.myacc1.Name}"/>
    <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!wrap.checkbox1}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Col 2">
   <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.myacc2.Name}"/>
   <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!wrap.checkbox2}"/>
 </apex:column>
  <apex:column headerValue="Col 1">
    <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.myacc3.Name}"/>
    <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!wrap.checkbox3}"/>
   </apex:column>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: this kind of doesn't answer the question - OP is looking for a solution using `apex:selectCheckboxes` with jQuery rearranging the VF-generated HTML